# vb.net form and jquery validation

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

i have a vb.net form button that go through a jquery validation before excude a function in the code behind , actually in either ways if the validation is true or false the function stopped and never call the vb.net function how can i make the it proceed to the code behind ?

vb.net form (textbox and button )

```
      <asp:TextBox ID="ToCc" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="emailSend" runat="server" Text="send" />
```

jquery :

```
   $("#<%=emailSend.ClientID %>").click(function(){
          if($("#<%=ToCc.ClientID %>").val() == ""){
            alert("this fienld can't be empty") ; 
            return false ; 
          } else{
    return true ; 
}

         });
```

the email click vb function is

```
 Protected Sub emailSend_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles 

    emailSend.Click

   MsgBox("do any thing ") 

   End Sub
```

Comment: you can declare the method shared and decorate it with [WebMethod] attribute and then call that method using jquery ajax to send email asynchronously if you want to use jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't assigned your emailSend_Click method as the event handler for the button. Secondly, you can use the [RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx) to accomplish your validation goals.

Try `<asp:Button ID="emailSend" runat="server" Text="send" onclick="emailSend_Click" />`

Additionally, remove the statement `emailSend.Click` from your code behind. You are already in the click event handler.

Comment: @MinaGabriel Why the insistence on using jquery? If you use a RequiredFieldValidator then it will automatically do the check server-side too, which you must do anyway - never trust the data sent back from the client.

Answer (score 0):

this is jquery version

```
$('input[id$=emailSend]').click(function(){
if($('input[id$=ToCc]').val() == ''){
            alert("this fienld can't be empty") ; 
            return false ; 
          } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

More concise and a little more "jQuery"'d:

```
$("#<%=emailSend.ClientID %>").click(function(event) { 
      if($("#<%=ToCc.ClientID %>").val() == "") { 
        alert("this field can't be empty") ;  
        event.preventDefault(); 
      }  
});
```

By default it'll return true if everything is OK.

Comment: $("#<%=emailSend.ClientID %>") will look for an element with <%=emailSend.ClientID %> as ID look at SLAKS comment

Comment: Erm, no it'll not, the `<%= emailSend.ClientID %>` will write the full client ID to the script when the page loads as it's ASP.NET - I've done this many times without any problems. Using a attribute search just puts more load on the browser to search the DOM.

Comment: You can't use it in a separate js file anyway

Comment: That is true, and a good point to bear in mind should you site be laid out this way.